# What cipher could this be?

Tags: cipher

So, I've been asked by a friend to help him solve this:

```
hGoqqgAbsdgisNiae-afIaobneBoksfnjeiawAoavjeasdTdnadkTmafnfqLocddlskcoanEgabddfdBhunkjaneEpoaadrlbeAmvasbrnR
```

The problem is --- I've never seen a ciphertext that looks like this! I tried some basic ciphers (like Caesar) but got nowhere.

Comment: More downvotes without any effort put in to explaining why... pretty poor.

Comment: I guess they "meant" to say this http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do but couldn't be bothered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

> At some intervals there is a capital letter.
>
>   They form: Gani, Battle Bear.

Comment: Oh! This was my first idea, yes, but I managed to miss the capital "I"... Sorry